# Economics.SE is closing, can we salvage some of the questions?

Tags: discussion, migration

I hadn't even heard that there was an [Economics Stack Exchange](https://economics.stackexchange.com) site before I learned that [it will be closed down next week](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/) along with a bunch of other quiescent beta sites.

> **Update:** As planned, the original Economics Stack Exchange was shut down shortly after I posted this back in 2012.  A few years later, in 2014, a *new* Economics site was created at the same URL, and as of 2019 seems to be doing fine.  This meta post is thus now only a historical curiosity.  Sorry for any confusion!
>
> <sup>As a side effect of shutting down the site and recreating it from scratch, the database (including all post and user IDs) was reset.  Thus, any links to questions on the old Economics site below will, if clicked, now take you to a random question (or answer) on the new site that just happens to have the same ID number.  I have <s>struck out</s> such broken links in this post.</sup>

It now looks like many of the other sites are going to be fully or partially [absorbed into more active SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130342/salvage-questions-on-closed-sites-via-migration) with overlapping topics, where their questions can remain on the web and receive the tender care of an active community.

I already suggested that [Math.SE might want some of the Econ.SE questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4049/economics-se-is-closing-can-we-salvage-some-of-the-questions), but it strikes me that others (particularly those on [econometrics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/econometrics)) might fit better here.  What do you folks think?

I've <s>[posted about this on the Economics meta](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165/salvaging-questions-by-migration)</s>, where I've also listed several other sites that might want some of the questions, but I'd like to request opinions and help from the Statistics community here.  If you'd like to help in keeping the more statistical questions from Economics.SE on the web, here's what you can do:

- Express your support for migrating these questions here, so that the SE folks can tell that the community here is (as I hope, at least) in favor of it.
- Go through the list of [questions on Economics.SE](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions) and look for ones that would be on topic here.
- Collect links to the questions here, so that we can point an Economics mod at them before the site closes ([example of such a list at SF&F meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1746/literature-is-closing-what-questions-should-we-migrate-here)).  Or you could just flag the questions for migration directly, but this way we avoid needless duplicate flags.

Note that there are only 412 questions total on Economics.SE, so having someone who knows the topic review them all would not necessarily be an overwhelming task.

(Personal disclaimer: I'm neither an economist not a statistician, and I haven't been active on either of these sites.  I do have a passing interest in both topics, and I feel like I should at least make an effort to salvage some of these questions before they end up just gathering digital dust in a compressed archive somewhere.)

Comment: Good idea - Can someone please explain the mechanics of migrating a question from Economics.SE to Crossvalidated.SE.

Comment: @Ben: The same way you'd migrate questions between any other sites that don't have a predefined migration path: by flagging them and asking a moderator to do it. But it's probably worth noting that this meta post is from 2012, and the current [economics.se] site is [not the same site as the one that was shut down back then](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-will-this-be-different-from-the-previous-economics-site).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is obsolete. The old Economics site which this post is about was shut down in 2012, and a new site was created in its place in 2014.

Answer (score 11):

Among the first page of newest questions and the first page of highest-voted questions (with almost no overlap) I was able to find exactly one question that might be of interest here.

There isn't even a "statistics" tag on that site!

There is an "econometrics" tag gracing 31 of the questions.  About a third of those might be suitable for migration here (and wouldn't duplicate an existing post):

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/154/what-are-the-major-philosophical-methodological-and-terminological-differences

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/202/does-it-make-sense-to-cluster-when-you-use-a-regression-discontinuity

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/621/when-should-one-consider-using-gmm

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/estimating-demand-elasticity-econometrically

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/346/example-of-estimation-vs-calibration

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/304/in-structural-econometrics-what-is-meant-by-simulation-variance

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/192/if-you-have-a-really-big-n-is-using-a-regular-vs-an-m-n-bootstrap-ever-a-good

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/191/fixed-effects-models-vs-models-where-years-serve-as-instruments

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1153/regressing-price-on-volume

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1143/what-is-the-reason-why-we-use-natural-logarithm-ln-rather-than-log-to-base-10

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/853/vector-autoregression-number-of-variables-to-use

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1224/how-to-hypothesis-test-a-fraction-of-two-coefficients

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/would-it-make-sense-to-do-a-2sls-regression-for-nominal-gdp-and-money-supply

This is a generous list: it includes anything that looked reasonable based on the title and first couple of lines.  It would be fine if they were migrated but little would be lost if they weren't.

Comment: Okay, so game theory is on topic on Math.SE, apparently. What about this question: http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/302/using-econometrics-how-do-i-solve-out-the-endogeneity-problem ? I haven't received an answer that I find satisfactory, and identifying an appropriate intermediate variable is incredibly difficult. Would this question fit here?

Comment: Hi @Aarthi, yes, that one looks appropriate too.  I had skipped over it because on CV just about any question that mentions "endogeneity" seems not to get any accepted answer (unless it focuses on correlation or collinearity :-)).

Comment: Haha, that's totally understandable! It's a really tough issue that doesn't have one really good answer. Techniques for identifying potential intermediate variables might be how that question needs to be rephrased, and hopefully that will garner better answers. :)

Comment: @whuber, just looking at the titles, these seem like reasonably straightforward econometrics questions an average Ph.D. economics student would be asking when they were told to apply a particular econometric technique without helpful guidance from the adviser. They can be migrated here with some special tagging, but frankly I doubt that we have a huge presence of econometricians on CV to answer these questions much better than economists have done so far on their website. I could probably pass as an econometrician, but that's a rather distant shot.

Comment: @StasK Consider this an opportunity to shore up the `econometrics` tag here on CV? :D All joking aside, I'm reasonably certain the *really good* econometricians will stumble over here by necessity.

Comment: Thanks for compiling this list! Ps. What do you folks think about [this homework question](http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-to-extract-a-set-of-values-from-a-specific-range-of-indexes)? I see it was suggested for migration here when it was first asked. Myself, I have no idea what a "chaining index" is, so I can tell if it would fit here or not.

Comment: @Ilmari That's purely a question of arithmetic, not of statistics.  It asks the respondent to multiply lists of values by 207/100 or 100/207.

Comment: @whuber: ...oh. So it's _that_ basic. \*slaps forehead\* I guess I was more tired last night than I thought. Anyway, thanks. :)

Comment: I'm the last mod standing on Economics.SE - would it be ok to start migrating this lot?

Comment: @Turukawa Please go ahead.  Thank you for your dedication!

Comment: I have migrated this list.  Thanks so much for the support and don't feel obliged to keep them if they don't work for you guys.  Grateful for the consideration.

Comment: @Turukawa: It looks like three questions on the list were not migrated. Was there a reason or did you just miss them?

Comment: Missed them ... ;p

Comment: My feeling is that we have more than enough questions on this site.  We don't need to add a lot of old ones from another site even if they fit well here.  I think probably members from the economics community having lost their home might migrate to statistics or at least post here more frequently.  I think it would be better to get fresh questions on those topics.